# Singly linked list sorting using subscript overload

Tags: c++, overloading, singly-linked-list

I cannot figure out how to get my singly linked list into my sort method. I'm supposed to overload the subscript to be able to access the different parts of my list. The issue i run into is figuring out how to modify this list through the sort function.

```
template <typename E> 
class SNode {
private:
    E elem;
    SNode<E>* next;
    friend class SLinkedList<E>;
    template <typename E>
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, SLinkedList<E>& v);
};

template <typename E> 
class SLinkedList {
 public:
    SLinkedList();
    ~SLinkedList();
    bool empty() const;
    const E& front() const;
    void addFront(const E& e);
    void removeFront();
    int getSize();
    SNode<E>* getHead();
    void sort();
    void printDetails() const;

    //overload

    E& operator[] (const int index);
    const E& operator[] (const int index) const;

private:
    SNode<E>* head;
    int size;
 };
    template <typename E>
    E& SLinkedList<E>::operator [](const int index) {
    SNode<E>* temp = head;

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    E out = temp->elem;
    return out;
    }

template <typename E>
const E& SLinkedList<E>::operator [](const int index) const {
    SNode<E>* temp = head;

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }    
    E out = temp->elem;
    return out;
}

template <typename E>
void SLinkedList<E>::sort() {
    for (int i = 1; i < getSize(); ++i) {
        E curr = (*this)[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && (*this)[j] > curr); {
            E temp = (*this)[i];
            this->elem = (*this)[j];
            this[j] = temp;
            j = j - 1;
        }
        (*this)[j + 1] = curr;

    }
}

void main() {
SLinkedList<float> lst;

int lstElems = 10;
srand(time(NULL));
for (int i = 0; i < lstElems; i++) {
    lst.addFront(randGen());
}
cout << "Unsorted list: " << lst << endl;
lst.printDetails();
cout << "TEST SINGLE LIST ELEMENT: " << lst[1] << endl;
lst.sort();
cout << "Sorted list: " << lst << endl;



system("pause");
```

}

Comment: Accessing list by operator `[]` is O(i) where i would be the accessed position; this constrains the performance of any sorting method to be  O(n^2) at least, maybe worse. Operator `[]` works for arrays because their access is O(1), but with a list is not thus. You must design your sorting method without thinking in positions. A clue: think in the insertion sort for a quadratic algorithm or in divider/conquer strategy for getting a O(n log n) -quicksort or mergesort-. Curiously, divide/conquer algorithms are easier for sorting lists than for arrays. Good luck

Comment: I agree that this is a really stupid way of sorting the list, but it's what's required for the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

```
Reviewing your code, you seem to have an incorrect implementation of bubble sort.
The below impl is for bubble sort. (do remember there are better sorting algorithms than bubble sort, which i won't get into )
      int j = 0; 

      while (swapped) {

            swapped = false;

            j++;

        for (int i=0; i < getSize() - j; i++) {

        if ((*this)[i] > (*this)[i+1]) {

            E temp = (*this)[i];

            (*this)[i] = (*this)[i+1];

            (*this)[i+1]=temp;

            swapped = true;

        }

        }

    }
```

Comment: The issue is getting my sort method to actually sort the list